# Various set operations and the empty set...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \Bigr\{ \{\}, \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, a, \text{cat}, \{1, a, \text{cat}\} \Bigr\}$.

Determine the sets.

(a) $A \setminus \{ a, b, c \} = \Bigr\{ \{\}, \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, \text{cat}, \{1, a, \text{cat}\} \Bigr\}$.

(b) $A \cup \{ x \} = \Bigr\{ \{\}, \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, a, \text{cat}, \{1, a, \text{cat}\}, x \Bigr\}$.

(c) $A \cap \{ \text{cat}, \text{dog}, \text{mouse} \} = \{ \text{cat} \}$.

(d) $A \ \{\} = \Bigr\{ \{\}, \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, a, \text{cat}, \{1, a, \text{cat}\} \Bigr\}$.

(e) $A \ \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\} = \Bigr\{ \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, a, \text{cat}, \{1, a, \text{cat}\} \Bigr\}$.

(f) $A \Delta \bigr\{ a, b, \{1, a, \text{cat}\} \bigr\} = \Bigr\{ \{\}, \bigr\{\{\}\bigr\}, 1, \text{cat}, b \Bigr\}$.

A contains the empty set and a set containing the empty set.

I'd like someone to confirm my solutions. I want to make sure I understand these operations.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I wanted to confirm my understanding as some elements repeat within other elements. Also, I wanted to understand these operations in terms of the empty set.

Comment: Ah, OK. The empty set can have two "roles". It can either be treated as a set, and so it's a valid operand of any set operation like union. But it can also be treated as an ordinary object, so it can be put inside a set.

Comment: As for the other part of the question, it's answered by the people below...

Comment: Can you truly ever remove the empty set from a set? Doesn't it contain "no elements" & in a sense; is always inside a set?

Comment: Yes. The empty set conatins no objects, so you can't remove anything from it- this is treating it as a set. But, if you treat it as an object, which is its other "role", then it is just a "thing" that can be removed/added to any set you like.

Comment: Note that one set being a subset of another, and one set being an element of another, are different things. Even though the empty set is a subset of every set, it is not an *element* of every set.

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you got those correct except for (f), where the element $b$ needs to be included in the set.  The symmetric difference is the set of elements that lie in exactly one of the two sets.  Since $b$ is in the second set but not in the first set, $b$ should be included in the symmetric difference.

Comment: Yes, believe it or not; that was a typo in making this post with haste (I had my answers written down before posting this question). Good to know.

Comment: It's ok, if you define the members of these sets in a certain way. However,set theorists often consider the finite ordinal sets and the natural numbers to be the same things,with 0 ={} and 1={0}={{}}. This is because they want every thing to be a set (except when it's a proper class, which in most formulations, are not things, but  just abbreviations . As Humpty Dumpty said : It is,except when it isn't.) Is that confusing enough?

Answer (score 0):

(a) - (e) are correct; Answer of (f) should be $\{ \{ \}, \{ \{\} \}, 1, b, cat \}$.